# Decrement voltage by 500 volts each iteration

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having some issues with running a batch file to decrement voltage by 500.
This line give me some problem:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
set COM_PORT=com5

set Voltage=3000

:start
echo "setting voltage to %Voltage%"
set Voltage=%Voltage%-500
echo "setting next voltage to %Voltage%"
pause
goto start
```

The issue is that the voltage doesn't decrement per each iteration.

Comment: Have you defined `Voltage1` somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `set` inside the loop?

Comment: `%Voltage% = %Voltage% - 500`?

Comment: doesnt work. It gives me error "'3000' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This absolutely works!!

```
    @ECHO OFF
    cls
    set COM_PORT=com5

    set Voltage=3000

    :start
    echo "setting voltage to %Voltage%"
    set /A Voltage = %Voltage% - 500
    echo "setting next voltage to %Voltage%"
    pause
    goto start
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `/a` switch in your `set /a Voltage = %Voltage% - 500`.  You can also get rid of the percent signs in `set /a` commands, like `set /a Voltage = Voltage - 500`; and assignment operators work as well.  `set /a Voltage -= 500`.  But the most efficient solution would be a `for /L` loop.

```js
@echo off & setlocal
set "COM_PORT=com5"

for /L %%I in (3000, -500, 0) do (
    set /a "Voltage=%%I"
    echo Setting next voltage to %%I
    pause
)
```

Do `set /?` and `for /?` in a cmd console for full details.

Comment: How would i create an exit condition using if statement. for example if I wanted to exit the loop say when the voltage reaches 1500 Volts.

Comment: You could use a `goto` and add a label after the end of the `for` loop.  Or you could just `for /L %%I in (3000, -500, 1500) do (` etc.  The syntax for `for /L` is `for /L %%x in (start, step, end) do commands`.